# how to auto generate a Varchar in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to feed a number to database in this case my reference number which is of a (AAA/BBB/28AUG2015 - 4082) format, which should be selected by user,and the date should be the system date while the last number should be auto-generated in that sequence.the 1st and 2nd values are fixed.

Kindly I am unable to do that on mysql Database.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL trigger : [Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)